# How to get number of days of specific type per week

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, sql-server-2012

If I have table like this:

```
emp_num trans_date  day_type
5667    2016-03-01  1
5667    2016-03-02  1
5667    2016-03-03  1
5667    2016-03-04  3
5667    2016-03-05  3
5667    2016-03-06  1
5667    2016-03-07  1
5667    2016-03-08  1
5667    2016-03-09  1
5667    2016-03-10  1
5667    2016-03-11  3
5667    2016-03-12  3
5667    2016-03-13  1
5667    2016-03-14  1
5667    2016-03-15  1
5667    2016-03-16  1
5667    2016-03-17  1
5667    2016-03-18  3
5667    2016-03-19  3
5667    2016-03-20  1
5667    2016-03-21  1
5667    2016-03-22  1
5667    2016-03-23  1
5667    2016-03-24  1
5667    2016-03-25  3
5667    2016-03-26  3
5667    2016-03-27  1
5667    2016-03-28  1
5667    2016-03-29  1
5667    2016-03-30  1
5667    2016-03-31  1
```

Given that every employee must have all month days in `trans_date`.

How to get all the employees who have **more than** two `day_type =3` **per at least one week through a given month in a year**?

Comment: this is really broad, what happens when the week is within 2 different months. Which kind of week are you asking for - iso week ? same iso week can range over 2 different years

Comment: @t-clausen.dk if the week in two different months then the same rule , check the part of week  contain more than  two (day_type =3) for a particular employee

Comment: again, how do you define a week ? US week, Iso week or other ?

Comment: @t-clausen.dk : Excuse me i don't know exactly the difference between those types but we use the standard .

Comment: does the week start on a monday or sunday, can the first week of the year have days in the previous year ?

Comment: @t-clausen.dk the week start with `Sunday`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @month int = 3,
        @year int = 2016

;WITH cte AS (
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES
                        (5667, '2016-03-01', 1),(5667, '2016-03-02', 1),(5667, '2016-03-03', 1),(5667, '2016-03-04', 3),(5667, '2016-03-05', 3),(5667, '2016-03-06', 1), --2
(5667, '2016-03-07', 1),(5667, '2016-03-08', 1),(5667, '2016-03-09', 1),(5667, '2016-03-10', 1),(5667, '2016-03-11', 3),(5667, '2016-03-12', 3),(5667, '2016-03-13', 1), --2
(5667, '2016-03-14', 1),(5667, '2016-03-15', 1),(5667, '2016-03-16', 1),(5667, '2016-03-17', 1),(5667, '2016-03-18', 3),(5667, '2016-03-19', 3),(5667, '2016-03-20', 1), --2
(5667, '2016-03-21', 1),(5667, '2016-03-22', 1),(5667, '2016-03-23', 1),(5667, '2016-03-24', 1),(5667, '2016-03-25', 3),(5667, '2016-03-26', 3),(5667, '2016-03-27', 1), --2
(5667, '2016-03-28', 1),(5667, '2016-03-29', 1),(5667, '2016-03-30', 1),(5667, '2016-03-31', 1),                                                                         --0

                        (4275, '2016-03-01', 3),(4275, '2016-03-02', 1),(4275, '2016-03-03', 1),(4275, '2016-03-04', 3),(4275, '2016-03-05', 1),(4275, '2016-03-06', 3), --3
(4275, '2016-03-07', 3),(4275, '2016-03-08', 3),(4275, '2016-03-09', 1),(4275, '2016-03-10', 1),(4275, '2016-03-11', 3),(4275, '2016-03-12', 1),(4275, '2016-03-13', 1), --3
(4275, '2016-03-14', 3),(4275, '2016-03-15', 3),(4275, '2016-03-16', 1),(4275, '2016-03-17', 1),(4275, '2016-03-18', 3),(4275, '2016-03-19', 1),(4275, '2016-03-20', 1), --3
(4275, '2016-03-21', 3),(4275, '2016-03-22', 3),(4275, '2016-03-23', 1),(4275, '2016-03-24', 1),(4275, '2016-03-25', 3),(4275, '2016-03-26', 1),(4275, '2016-03-27', 1), --3
(4275, '2016-03-28', 3),(4275, '2016-03-29', 3),(4275, '2016-03-30', 1),(4275, '2016-03-31', 1),                                                                         --2

                        (9922, '2016-03-01', 1),(9922, '2016-03-02', 1),(9922, '2016-03-03', 1),(9922, '2016-03-04', 3),(9922, '2016-03-05', 3),(9922, '2016-03-06', 1), --2
(9922, '2016-03-07', 1),(9922, '2016-03-08', 1),(9922, '2016-03-09', 1),(9922, '2016-03-10', 1),(9922, '2016-03-11', 3),(9922, '2016-03-12', 3),(9922, '2016-03-13', 1), --2
(9922, '2016-03-14', 1),(9922, '2016-03-15', 1),(9922, '2016-03-16', 1),(9922, '2016-03-17', 1),(9922, '2016-03-18', 3),(9922, '2016-03-19', 3),(9922, '2016-03-20', 1), --2
(9922, '2016-03-21', 3),(9922, '2016-03-22', 3),(9922, '2016-03-23', 1),(9922, '2016-03-24', 1),(9922, '2016-03-25', 1),(9922, '2016-03-26', 1),(9922, '2016-03-27', 1), --2
(9922, '2016-03-28', 3),(9922, '2016-03-29', 1),(9922, '2016-03-30', 3),(9922, '2016-03-31', 1)                                                                          --2
) AS t (emp_num, trans_date, day_type)
)
,final AS (
SELECT  DATEPART(week,c.trans_date) as week_num,
        emp_num,
        COUNT(c.trans_date) as coun
FROM cte c 
WHERE day_type = 3 
    AND DATEPART(month,trans_date) = @month
    AND DATEPART(YEAR,trans_date) = @year
GROUP BY emp_num,
        DATEPART(week,c.trans_date)
HAVING COUNT(c.trans_date) > 2
)

SELECT f.emp_num
FROM final f
GROUP BY emp_num
```

Output:

```
emp_num
-----------
4275

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: This is what I started with. However, the requirement is to return only those employees who have more than or equal to 2 `day_type = 3` rows in EVERY week in the month. This just gets employees who have more than or equal to 2 `day_type = 3` rows in ONE week during the month. Only employee 4275 should be returned NOT 5667.

Comment: thanks but wrong result ,ex:i got `9922`
`9922 2016-03-01 1
9922 2016-03-02 1
9922 2016-03-03 1
9922 2016-03-04 3
9922 2016-03-05 3
9922 2016-03-06 1
9922 2016-03-07 1
9922 2016-03-08 1
9922 2016-03-09 1
9922 2016-03-10 1
9922 2016-03-11 3
9922 2016-03-12 3
9922 2016-03-13 1
9922 2016-03-14 1
9922 2016-03-15 1
9922 2016-03-16 1
9922 2016-03-17 1
9922 2016-03-18 3
9922 2016-03-19 3
9922 2016-03-20 1
9922 2016-03-21 3
9922 2016-03-22 3
9922 2016-03-23 1
9922 2016-03-24 1
9922 2016-03-25 1
9922 2016-03-26 1
9922 2016-03-27 1
9922 2016-03-28 3
9922 2016-03-29 1
9922 2016-03-30 3
9922 2016-03-31 1`

Comment: this employee should n't be in the result because it has just 2 `day_type = 3` per week through the month

Comment: @AnynameDonotcare more then 2? then change `HAVING COUNT(c.trans_date) >= 2` to `HAVING COUNT(c.trans_date) > 2`

Comment: when i do this change i get no result at all although `4275` should be there for example

Comment: okay but it has 3 times in the second,third and forth weeks more than 2 (day_type =3)

Comment: @AnynameDonotcare `4275` has only 2 special days on last week of the month

Comment: if the employee has at least one week with more than 2(day_type =3) then i want to appear in the result

Comment: In your question: more than two day_type =3 **per all weeks** through a given month in a year?

Comment: no per week not all weeks , if any week for the employee has more than two
`day_type =3` then it should be in the result

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood you.. please check my answer one more time. I have edited it.

Comment: Thanks a lot it works finally , i test some data and sound every thing okay.
but i have one question:
1- if i want my week to begin with `sat` rather than `sun` for example, how to handle it .

Comment: SET DATEFIRST 6. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181598.aspx may help you. And don't  forget to set it back to default :)

Comment: Yes, in the beginning

Comment: @gofr1 : Thank U so much :)

Answer (score 2):

Given the data provided by you:

```
declare  @table1 table (emp_num int, trans_date datetime, day_type int)
insert into @table1
VALUES (5667,'2016-03-01',1),(5667,'2016-03-02',1),(5667,'2016-03-03',1),
(5667,'2016-03-04',3),(5667,'2016-03-05',3),(5667,'2016-03-06',1),
(5667,'2016-03-07',1),(5667,'2016-03-08',1),(5667,'2016-03-09',1),
(5667,'2016-03-10',1),(5667,'2016-03-11',3),(5667,'2016-03-12',3),
(5667,'2016-03-13',1),(5667,'2016-03-14',1),(5667,'2016-03-15',1),
(5667,'2016-03-16',1),(5667,'2016-03-17',1),(5667,'2016-03-18',3),
(5667,'2016-03-19',3),(5667,'2016-03-20',1),(5667,'2016-03-21',1),
(5667,'2016-03-22',1),(5667,'2016-03-23',1),(5667,'2016-03-24',1),
(5667,'2016-03-25',3),(5667,'2016-03-26',3),(5667,'2016-03-27',1),
(5667,'2016-03-28',1),(5667,'2016-03-29',1),(5667,'2016-03-30',1),
(5667,'2016-03-31',1),(4275,'2016-03-01',3),(4275,'2016-03-02',1),
(4275,'2016-03-03',1 ),(4275,'2016-03-04',3 ),(4275,'2016-03-05',1 ),
(4275,'2016-03-06',1 ),(4275,'2016-03-07',3 ),(4275,'2016-03-08',3 ),
(4275,'2016-03-09',1 ),(4275,'2016-03-10',1 ),(4275,'2016-03-11',3 ),
(4275,'2016-03-12',1 ),(4275,'2016-03-13',1 ),(4275,'2016-03-14',3 ),
(4275,'2016-03-15',3 ),(4275,'2016-03-16',1 ),(4275,'2016-03-17',1 ),
(4275,'2016-03-18',3 ),(4275,'2016-03-19',1 ),(4275,'2016-03-20',1 ),
(4275,'2016-03-21',3 ),(4275,'2016-03-22',3 ),(4275,'2016-03-23',1 ),
(4275,'2016-03-24',1),(4275,'2016-03-25',3 ),(4275,'2016-03-26',1 ),
(4275,'2016-03-27',1 ),(4275,'2016-03-28',3 ),(4275,'2016-03-29',3 ),
(4275,'2016-03-30',1 ),(4275,'2016-03-31',1)
```

This will get you what you are looking for (`emp_num` 5667 not returned, `emp_num` 4275 returned) although bear in mind that some months will have weeks that span two months so you may need to tweak it if your requirements for this are more subtle:

```
 declare @year int = 2016,
 @month int = 3

 ;with emp_cte (emp_num, weeknum, day_type_count)
 as
 (
     select emp_num, 
         datepart(week, trans_date), 
         sum(case when day_type = 3 then 1 else 0 end)
     from @table1 t
     where year(trans_date) = @year
     and month(trans_date) = @month
     group by emp_num, datepart(week, trans_date)
 )

 select emp_num
 from emp_cte
 group by emp_num
 having min(day_type_count) >= 2
```

Comment: From re-reading your initial post am I right in saying that you only want employees returned who have had more than 2 `day_type=3` entries EVERY week in a given month - rather than just once in a given month (which is what my current query gives you)?

Comment: Exactly,this what i mean

Comment: I've amended my answer accordingly @Anyname Donotcare.

Comment: it's so slow ,run for ever !!

Comment: Yes, the results were correct, but the `NOT EXISTS` with `EXCEPT` did result in a lot of table scans upon inspection! Have reworked the query which should perform much better - and gives the same results.

Comment: Thanks,but some results are wrong like :
`9922 2016-03-01 1 9922 2016-03-02 1 9922 2016-03-03 1 9922 2016-03-04 3 9922 2016-03-05 3 9922 2016-03-06 1 9922 2016-03-07 1 9922 2016-03-08 1 9922 2016-03-09 1 9922 2016-03-10 1 9922 2016-03-11 3 9922 2016-03-12 3 9922 2016-03-13 1 9922 2016-03-14 1 9922 2016-03-15 1 9922 2016-03-16 1 9922 2016-03-17 1 9922 2016-03-18 3 9922 2016-03-19 3 9922 2016-03-20 1 9922 2016-03-21 3 9922 2016-03-22 3 9922 2016-03-23 1 9922 2016-03-24 1 9922 2016-03-25 1 9922 2016-03-26 1 9922 2016-03-27 1 9922 2016-03-28 3 9922 2016-03-29 1 9922 2016-03-30 3 9922 2016-03-31 1`

Comment: this employee should n't be in the result because it has just `2 day_type = 3` per week through the month,i need only the employees who have more than two days of type 3 per week in the given month

Comment: @AnynameDonotcare, is it > 2 or >= 2 occurrences you want? If it is > 2 then none of the given employees would be returned as even 4275 has only 2 occurrences in the first and last weeks of the month...

Comment: if the employee has at least one week with more than 2(day_type =3) then i want to appear in the result

Answer (score 1):

Something along the lines of below.  `DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, trans_date), 0)` will convert the date into the "first of the month", then the `EOMONTH` will do "end of the month", effectively bounding your "given month" (`@GIVEN_MONTH_DATE`).

```
DECLARE @GIVEN_MONTH_DATE DATE = '2016-04-01'
DECLARE @WEEKS_IN_MONTH = DATEDIFF(week, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @GIVEN_MONTH_DATE), 0), EOMONTH(@GIVEN_MONTH_DATE))

WITH results AS (
    SELECT
        emp_num AS EmployeeNumber,
        DATEPART(week, trans_date) AS Week,
        day_type AS DayType,
        COUNT(emp_num) AS Total
    FROM
        table
    WHERE
        day_type = 3
        AND trans_date BETWEEN DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @GIVEN_MONTH_DATE), 0) AND EOMONTH(@GIVEN_MONTH_DATE)
    GROUP BY
        emp_num,
        DATEPART(week, trans_date),
        day_type
    HAVING
        COUNT(emp_num) > 2
)

SELECT
    EmployeeNumber,
    SUM(Total) AS Transactions
FROM
    results
GROUP BY
    EmployeeNumber
HAVING
    COUNT(EmployeeNumber) = @WEEKS_IN_MONTH
```

Comment: This will give you every week that each employee has more than 2 `day_type = 3` instances. It will not return only those employees who have more than 2  `day_type = 3` instances in EVERY week in the month, which is the requirement. As such both employees 5667 and 4275 will be returned - incorrectly.

Comment: Now it should meet his requirement.  It's pseudocode-esque considering I didn't actually run it, but it should be close enough to get him going

Comment: It's a grey area as to which weeks need to be counted but the `DATEDIFF` only counts those week boundaries crossed. Thus it returns 4 weeks in this case. However the dataset contains 5 different weeks with the first and last one having 5 days. I think some clarification of exact requirements may be necessary but in this case a comment to a (now-deleted) answer mentioned that employee 4275 should be returned but not 5667 (see my data for these records). Your query currently does the opposite.